# Change Login Screen (Greeter) Theme

Tags: release-loki, display, greeter

Is it possible to change the look of the login screen on Elementary OS Loki to something other than the default (pantheon greeter)? The text resolution is pretty low and my profile picture is strangely cropped. Also it doesn't match the gtk/icons theme I use (using tweaks) once I'm logged in. If anyone knows a method to customize the login screen, please do share.

[image: screenshot]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help, but lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings package might work, then again it might also change the whole thing since I'm pretty sure the greeter is a customized version of the normal LightDM but for Pantheon. Also, there may be a setting you could tweak with dconf-editor.